# Hibernate 6 getting null values from database for Json columns

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, hibernate-6.x

We updated our spring boot application from spring boot 2 to 3 and we found out that in some cases when we request the entity with a json field in it we receive null value for the json field instead of the value from the database.

At the moment we are using:

- java:17.0.2
- spring-boot:3.1.5
- hibernate:6.2.13
- mysql:8.0.36

Our class is similar to this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_name")
public class Table {
... 
    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)
    @Column(name = "json_column_value")
    private JsonPOJO jsonColumnValue;

...

    public JsonPOJO getJsonPOJO() {
        return jsonColumnValue;
    }

    public void setJsonPOJO(JsonPOJO jsonColumnValue) {this.jsonColumnValue = jsonColumnValue; }
}
```

On persist the data is saved properly in the database but when we request it with the repository like `tableRepository.findOneWithEagerRelationships(@Param("id") Long id)`
in the most cases it returns the `Table` entity properly with the json column but in some cases the json column value is null.

The repository looks something like this:

```
    @Query("select t FROM Table t " +
        "left join fetch t.manyLazyStuff  " +
        "where t.id = :id")
    Table findOneWithEagerRelationships(@Param("id") Long id);
```

Here all the lazy fields are fetched. (Json columns are not...)

Our Jackson configuration looks like this:

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {

    /**
     * Support for Hibernate types in Jackson.
     */
    @Bean
    public Hibernate6Module hibernate6Module() {
        return new Hibernate6Module();
    }

    /**
     * Jackson Afterburner module to speed up serialization/deserialization.
     */
    @Bean
    public AfterburnerModule afterburnerModule() {
        return new AfterburnerModule();
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernatePropertiesCustomizer jsonFormatMapperCustomizer(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        return properties -> properties
            .put(AvailableSettings.JSON_FORMAT_MAPPER, new JacksonJsonFormatMapper(objectMapper));
    }
}
```

Can anybody help us to figure out why we receive null values for this json columns?

Any suggestion is appreciated!

**Update**
It seems that the issue is reproducible only with Mysql version 8.0.36
We were unable to find the reason why this happens but for now we use mysql v8.0.35